# Isolation experiment in the Soviet Union in 1967

Tags: soviet-union, experiment

I heard about an isolation experiment in the Soviet Union in 1967 where 3 men were closed in for over a year. One name was Andrej Boschkow (or something like that), but I could not find any more information about that. Does someone know this experiment and if so could they give some links or other sources with more information about it?

Comment: [This film](http://www.tvroscosmos.ru/402/) (in Russian) seems to be about that experiment, but I haven't watched it.

Comment: this video seem to be blocked all over the world...

Comment: This wikipedia article is about it (in russian), but still could not find english sources for it: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%E2%80%A6_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: 1967 Mars: the Secret Mission. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFX0gnHFCco

Answer (score 4):

Andrew Bozhko together with Violetta Gorodinskaya wrote a book about his experience in this experiment “A year in a Star-flight”(год в «звездолете») 1975.

From [Goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31109235)

> Год в "Звездолете"
> Андрей Божко, Виолетта Городинская
>
> Три человека целый год провели в герметическом помещении, имитирующем кабину космического корабля. Они испытывали не только работу систем жизнеобеспечения экипажей кораблей, но и возможности человеческого организма переносить длительные космические полеты. Об этом эксперименте и рассказывают А.Божко - биолог, один из непосредственных участников эксперимента, и В.Городинская - журналист, член группы обеспечения эксперимента.

Google Translated:

> Three people spent a whole year in a hermetic room that simulates the cockpit of a spacecraft. They tested not only the life support systems of the spacecraft crews, but also the ability of the human body to endure long-term space flights. A. Bozhko, a biologist, one of the direct participants in the experiment, and V. Gorodinskaya, a journalist, a member of the experiment support group, tell about this experiment.
> 160 pages, Paperback
> Published January 1, 1975